# Rudin theorem 8.5, questions about the proof

Tags: real-analysis

Here is the theorem:

[image]

[image]

My question is: As far as I know It is proved that the set of limit points of any set is closed. Therefore I am confused about the proof $A$ being open. Besides I wonder why $g$ is continuous at $x_{0}$?

Answer (score 0):

Once you know that $f=0$ in neighborhood of $x_0$ is follows that every point of this neighborhood is a limit point of $E$. Hence this neighborhood is contained in $A$ proving that $x_0$ is an interior point.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand the main idea here, but I wonder, $A$ being open contradicts the theorem stating that the set of limit points of any set is closed, doesn't it?

Comment: A set being open is not a contradiction to it being closed. In a connected space the only sets that are both open and closed are the empty set and the whole space. Many times we prove that a set is both open and closed to draw some important conclusions using this fact.

Comment: Ah, yes... That's the case exactly. Could you explain why $g$ should be continuous at $x_{0}$? I know that $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ but how does it affect the fact that $g$ is also continuous at $x_{0}$?

Comment: The sum of a convergent series of the type $\sum d_{k+m}(x-x_0)^{m}$  is always continuous.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But, why the fact that f is continuous at S implies that A is a subset of E?

Comment: @Caslu If $a \in A$ then there exists $(e_n) $ contained in $E$ with $e_n \to a$. $f(e_n)=0$ for all $n$ so $f(a)=0$ by continuity.

Comment: Thank you for your response!! That was the only missing point!